# I need to filter, based on a count, and return values in Python

Tags: python, django

How do I filter this for only the courses where `course_enrollment = 0`, where

```
courses = Course.objects.values('subject','course_title','grade_level_standards','day','roster_cap','zoom_link','syllabus_link','sped','ell','creation_date','course_teacher__first_name','course_teacher__last_name').annotate(class_time=Concat('hour', V(':') ,'minutes',V(' '),'am_pm'))
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Why dou you do string processing at the db level?

Comment: where is `course_enrollment` attribute? on `Course` model

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem why not?

Comment: @funnydman: because (a) a database should store content, not handle the *representation* of that content; (b) time processing is not that easy. Here for example it will format `1:4`, not `1:04`; (c) formatting datetime is culture dependent; and (d) you make it a lot harder to compare two (date)times with each other.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, I misread I thought OP *just* concatenate strings (it's ok to get full_name from first_name and last_name), but building any time objects in that way is really strange.

Comment: Yes, course_enrollment is on Course model